# Does WebClient.OpenFileAsync fire DownloadProgressChanged

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

According to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx,

OpenFileAsync should have DownloadProgressChanged firing whenever it makes progress.

I can't get it to fire at all. Fires fine with DownloadDataAsync and DownloadFileAsync instead though.

Here's a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}% Downloaded", e.ProgressPercentage);
        }

        static void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Open Read Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

For me the DownloadProgressChanged event never fires, although change to DownloadFileAsync or DownloadDataAsync and it does.

Comment: I actually have a different results (with .Net4).  With my tests DownloadProgressChanged fires perfectly when using DownloadDataAsync().  But if I try to use DownloadFileAsync() it will not fire at all!  :/

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, DownloadFileAsync() returns void so there is no way to know if it runs into an error as far as I can tell.  In my case I did not create the directory where I was downloading to.  That caused the method to error out and NOT fire any of the events.  After creating the download folder where my file was getting download to it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the framework source and as far as I can tell the OpenReadAsync never touches the stuff that triggers DownloadProgressChanged.

It doesn't call GetBytes like DownloadDataAsync and DownloadFileAsync do, which is what in turn appears to be kicking off the event.

To work around it I've just used DownloadDataAsync instead, which does trigger the event and allows me to provide UI feedback for the download. It returns a byte array instead of the stream I needed, but that's not an issue.

So I'm assuming that it's MSDN that's wrong here, and OpenReadAsync doesn't trigger DownloadProgressChanged.

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in my answer.  Claiming the answer yourself and downvoting mine is definitely not the spirit of this web site.  This quacks like a violation of the "attribution required" clause in this site's license.  I'll ask a moderator to have a look.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, apologies if I've done anything wrong. I guess perhaps I didn't word the question well enough. It really was a case of "am I going mad here or is MSDN talking scribble?"